# How to link a title to display the content in its side?

Tags: hyperref, links, bookmarks

My question is. How to make a latex code that links, like the titles are on the left side and the content will display in the  right side like the html style that you will link for it to easy to access by just clicking it. Thank you. I cant find any online converter of pdf to latex code.

Hoping for your response. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I think `hyperref` does that by default, you just have to open the bookmarks in the PDF viewer.  It that does not work for you, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduced the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I think, you mean the *outline* or *bookmarks* All unstarred structure commands as `\chapter`, `section` etc. will generate such a link in the bookmarks using `hyperref`, as Peter Grill suggested

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use an hyperref? and the output of it. everytime I use i encounter error or it will not run. Thank you

Comment: @JensenRuedas: The basic setup is done with `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the preamble already. That's all -- you should see the bookmarks then on the left side of the pdf viewer

Answer (score 4):

This is a minimal example how to use `hyperref` for bookmarks/outline

- If you want to have the bookmarks opened when the document is opened,
  use the option `bookmarksopened=true`
- If all bookmarks should be opened down to level of `subsubsection`, use the option `bookmarkopenlevel=4`, otherwise a smaller or even higher number. You need to set the
  `tocdepth` counter as well.

If additionally `\usepackage{bookmark}` is used, there will be some possibilities to 
control the appearance of bookmarks, for example. In this case, the bookmarks are generated on the first `pdflatex` run already, however, the ToC still needs two runs.

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbibind} % If the ToC should be in ToC and bookmarks
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}%
% For subsubsections to appear in ToC/bookmarks(if needed!)
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


\begin{document}
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents%



\chapter{First Chapter - Where it begins}

\section{Introduction}

\section{More stuff}

\subsection{Even more minor stuff}

\subsection{Other minor stuff}

\subsubsection{Going really deep}
\subsubsection{Going sideways}


\chapter{Repeating it over and over}

\section[Something different]{And now for something completely different}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) If you add [bookmark](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) you can get the links generated on the first run.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, I know, but the question was initially about `hyperref` ... I can add it afterwards